# Ethereum - In regard to its TPS

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I want to use Ethereum as private chain in a network. But as it would inside a transactional system, performance required is good. Ethereum on the other hand is said to have 15 TPS

What does 15 TPS mean ? That is not a practical performance if I try to use it for payment settlement in a private network

There would be probably 5000 - 6000 transactions per second and later more

How can I then use Ethereum for such a situation ?

Answer (score 2):

15TPS means that at any given second only 15 transaction can be processed by the network not more than that. These transaction can be simple value transfer or any smart contract transaction.

Yes I understand that 15TPS is very low, which makes Ethereum or any other major blockchain implementations to be not very scalable.
But please keep in mind that the Ethereum foundation is actively working to solve this problem this problem by **sharded blockchain** and other techniques.
So you can assume that in near future the TPS for Ethereum will be around 10000, which is good enough.
But if you want any immediate blockchain which provides such transaction capacities, than you have to look beyond Ethereum.

Comment: 15 TPS by entire network node means Ethereum is bad for private blockchain for payment and transactions, where there would be 1000s of transactions per second

Comment: It's important to note that the current 15 TPS is for the public blockchain. You may be able to do better with a private blockchain as you have more control over the number of miners, the bandwidth, the consensus model, difficulty, block processing time, etc. I don't know how much you can squeeze out of it, but I'm fairly certain you could do better than 15 TPS (but probably not 1000s).

Comment: @AdamKipnis A private blockchain makes 0 sense. If there are no conflicting stakeholders, then you could use stuff like Kafka or RabbitMQ which can offer millions of TPS. If there are, you fix the number, difficulty, permissions, and just use it an audited DB with consensus... which again makes it superceded by technologies like Cassandra DB, which uses consensus algos as well, if I'm not wrong.